# Simple Form non-model forms and i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n, ransack

I'm using `simple_form` to generate a search form for `ransack`. The form object passed in isn't an `ActiveRecord` object and so doesn't respond to `object_name`. This means I can't use the usual i18n structure for translating labels and hints etc...

```
simple_form:
    labels:
      search:
        id_gteq: ID greater than or equal to
        id_lteq: ID less than or equal to
```

My current solution is to pollute the default namespace:

```
simple_form:
    labels:
      defaults:
        id_gteq: ID greater than or equal to
        id_lteq: ID less than or equal to
```

Is there a better way? I thought of monkey patching `Ransack::Search` to add the `object_name` method. It would be better if I could pass the `object_name` through in the `simple_form_for` call but looking through the code, I don't think that's currently possible.

Here's an example field:

```
<%= form.input :id_gteq, :required => false %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your tries on file `ransack.en.yml`, You need to translate the attributes of **ransack** not **simple_form**

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. `simple_form` doesn't seem to delegate to these methods for the label and hint.